# Images not preview from run the public folder in Gatsby

Tags: node.js, gatsby, netlify

I'm beginner stage in Gatsby. As per Gatsby tuts, I did the develop and build the my first app in Gatsby. Also successfully generated public folder. All the preview render well in "http://localhost:8000/" as expected. But, when I directly run the index.html file from public folder, in the browser(using with/without localhost) it's not preview the images.  Could anyone tell me why? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Provide your `gatsby-config` to see how you've set your filesystem

Answer (score 0):

run: `gatsby build`  or `gatsby serve` and then try to open your website after running that command. Don't worry you can still work on it as usual after running build or serve commands.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Actually I did `gatsby build` and then `gatsby develop` in cmd. It's successfully generated Public folder. In "localhost:8000" preview render well with images. But Just I tried to run directly index.html file from the public folder. But, It's appear layout without images, Only HTML/CSS renders. Which file I need to share/upload in server to give others view/demo?

Answer (score 0):

> In "localhost:8000" preview render well with images. But Just I tried
> to run directly index.html file from the public folder. But, It's
> appear layout without images, Only HTML/CSS renders.

When you access `localhost:8000` you are accessing the `index.html` of your compiled project, but you can't take that file isolated because you have a bunch of bundled assets (JavaScript, images, CSS, etc).

When you run `gatsby build` you are compiling and bundling all your assets (React components, third-party dependencies, Gatsby's core dependencies, images, and their processing, etc) via webpack. All this bundle, surrounded by React's code, is outputted in the `/public` folder.

From the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/):

> `gatsby build` creates a version of your site with production-ready
> optimizations like packaging up your site’s config, data, and code,
> and creating all the static HTML pages that eventually get [rehydrated](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary#hydration)
> into a React application.
>
> **What do you get from a successful build?**
>
> When a Gatsby build is successfully completed, everything you need to
> deploy your site ends up in the `public` folder at the root of the site.
> The build includes minified files, transformed images, JSON files with
> information and data for each page, static HTML for each page, and
> more.
>
> The final build is just static files so it can now be [deployed](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/deploying-and-hosting/).
>
> You can run `gatsby serve` to test the output from compilation. If you
> make any new changes to the source code that you want to preview, you
> will have to rebuild the site and run `gatsby serve` again.

So, you can run directly the `index.html` file because you will be missing some assets, keys to the good operation of the project.

You also have a section in the docs related to [Deployment and Hosting](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/deploying-and-hosting/) as well as some related blog posts ([Deployment](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/tags/deployment/) and [Hosting](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/tags/hosting/) respectively).

`gatsby serve`, on the other hand, just opens the port in your local browser.

> Which file I need to share/upload in server to give others view/demo?

All the `/public` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's working great when deploy the site files (public folder) at the root of the site.

Comment: I'm glad you figure it out. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the issue